# Describing a section of a solid cone using spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus

I have to convert the following set to spherical coordinates.
$$S = \{(x, y, z)| 0 \le x \le 3, 0 \le y \le \sqrt{9 - x^2}, \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le z \le 9\}.$$
By visualizing the set, I have been able to figure out the bounds on $\theta$ and $\phi$. They are
$$0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$$
$$0 \le \phi \le \pi/4$$
Clearly $0$ is a lower bound for $\rho$, but I have been unable to get an upper bound. It think the upper bound must depend on just $\phi$, but I'm not sure how to get it.

Answer (score 1):

$S = \{(x, y, z)| 0 \le x \le 3, 0 \le y \le \sqrt{9 - x^2}, \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le z \le 9\}$

In spherical coordinates, we have two subsets, $S = S_1 \cup S_2$.

$x = \rho \cos\theta \sin\phi, y = \rho \sin\theta\sin\phi, z = \rho \cos\phi$

At the intersection of cone and cylinder,
$z = \rho \cos \phi = 3, \rho \sin \phi = 3 \implies \phi = \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ (equation of the cylinder in spherical coordinates is $\rho \sin \phi = 3$).

At the intersection of plane $z=9$ and the cylinder,
$z = \rho \cos\phi = 9, \rho \sin \phi = 3 \implies \phi = \arctan({\frac{1}{3}})$

(i) between $0 \leq \phi \leq \arctan({\frac{1}{3}}), 0 \leq \rho \leq 9 \sec \phi$
(as we are bound by the plane $z=9$)

(ii) Between $\arctan({\frac{1}{3}}) \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4}, 0 \leq \rho \leq 3 \csc \phi$ (as we are bound by the cylinder $\rho \sin \phi = 3)$

Lastly for both (i) and (ii), $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.